How can I cover all my skin (face+neck+body) while swimming outside (sea or outdoor pool) to avoid UV radiations?
What's the proper gear to cover all my skin (face+neck+body) while swimming outside (sea or outdoor pool) to avoid UV radiations? I am not
looking for specific product recommendations, but instead I'd like to know which types of products/materials/etc. are best for swimming (e.g., not a dry suit or a 7-mm-thick neoprene wetsuit). I only care about UV and swimming, and not the water temperature.

"Swim at night" isn't exactly a specific product recommendation, but it does solve this problem (while introducing others.)

@Roger That's my current solution indeed. The solution to cover all my skin may still apply as night swimming makes it easier to bump into unseen jellyfish though: How does lycra compare with neoprene gear in terms of jellyfish sting protection?.

A woman might do worse than looking at - quality - burkinis which seem to provide full-body coverage well enough.  Of course, that may leave you to argue about your sartorial choices with those who want to defend women's freedoms by telling women what not to wear.

I live in a country with high UV levels and consequent high skin cancer rates. The following is a distillation of the advice from health bodies in several countries. In my country 10 minutes in the summer sun is enough to get a sun burn if you are a fair-skinned person; people with darker skin ("olive complexion") still burn within 20 min. Melanistic skin types are still prone to skin cancers caused by UV exposure.
For the main body there are many different products available, most of them are similar to a rash vest in thickness and are suited for swimming. These are called UV swimwear or UV protection suits/swimwear or UPF swimwear. They come in a range of lengths from shorts to tops to full body, including head covering. A simple search will find you plenty of designs and recommendations from various bodies and publications. Regular clothing will help too, but can be restrictive while swimming, so not recommended in the water. A hat will work fine, but is a bit restrictive in the water, so if you are worried about your head under your hair, then get one with a hood.
For the feet, any closed footwear should be adequate, most of them are much thicker than regular clothes and layered so won't let sunlight through, but are not ideal for swimming. You can also use water booties (similar to those divers wear), often made out of the same materials as the UV protection swimwear with a sole.
For the face and hands a high SPF (sun protection factor) waterproof sunscreen or lip-gloss for the lips. This should be at least SPF-50 and should be applied at least 30 min before entering the water and at least 15 min before sun exposure to allow it to absorb into the skin and for the protection to work. These must be reapplied after exit from the water (i.e. can be rubbed off by towels) and will have a reapplication time after water usage and for general use; it might be something like every hour in the water or every two outside the water. Follow the instructions on the bottle, as not all last that long in the water or under the sun. Be prepared to be surprised by how much you should apply; a few dots doesn't cut it - for an arm, a stripe about the length of the fore-arm and 1/4"/6 mm wide should cover the whole arm when spread. You can get them in spray (aerosol) bottles as well as hand-pumped spray/squirt bottles - be warned they make it harder to get even and adequate coverage or to miss spots entirely. If on the water, make sure you apply on the under-surfaces of your nose, eye-brows, and chin - water reflects UV quite well and these normally not exposed places get burned very easily as any sailor or skier will tell you. Dermatology societies often have recommendations on brands and types for different usages. Most target UV-B and a few block UV-A as well as UV-B. Zinc-oxide ones block all types of UV (A, B, C), but do look like you've coloured yourself in with a paint-brush. I don't know how effective the "clear zinc" ones are, but the fully opaque ones work well on lips in my experience.
For the eyes, use a pair of UV filtering sunglasses or swimming goggles in the water. These should ideally be wrap-around (to minimize chance of light getting behind them). Your local sports shop should have some goggles in the swimwear aisle. It is important to not just get darkened glasses as these only open the pupil and thereby increase the risk of sun damage to the eyes by allowing UV to enter the eye and burn the retina. Don't trust the ones at the gas-station, despite stickers these often do nothing in the way of UV protection. Ask your optometrist for recommendations or buy from a specialist eyeglasses store.

Thanks! "It is important to not just get darkened glasses as these only open the pupil and thereby increase the risk of sun damage to the eyes by allowing UV to enter the eye and burn the retina" this is very interesting, I had never thought of it.

@FranckDernoncourt It basically boils down to the darkness opening the pupil more, so you get greater amounts of UV into the eye than you would without dark glasses because the lenses don't reduce the UV.  Apparently it's the cornea affected more than the retina, at least initially. Check out photo keratitis

It seems that the argument that sunglasses can increase the problem due to opening the pupil is a myth - the argument is that even the cheapest materials used in sunglasses filter UV quite well. e.g. https://www.quora.com/What-types-of-UV-protection-do-sunglasses-offer , https://www.reddit.com/r/sunglasses/comments/zep7vf/what_are_some_of_the_best_uv_protection_sunglasses/ . Polycarbonate itself (the base material of these glasses) has this property, it's not like additional expensive steps would be necessary for the manufacturer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polycarbonate

@AnoE The myth of cheap sunglasses not blocking UV comes from times before polycarbonate sunglasses where the norm. Glas is transmissive to UV and needs special coatings for UV protection, cheap manufacturers back then would save on that part.
Nowadays even the cheapest sunglasses are made out of polycarbonate and therefore have basically 100% UV protection.

That makes perfect sense, @airace3, thanks. I think it's safe to assume that there are no swimming goggles made from glass...

@AnoE thanks, I don't know about swimming goggles but coincidentally I was testing a few scuba masks for UV protection last week and, to my surprise, only one (namely, the Scubapro D-Mask) out of three provided serious UV protection. The other two were letting through a high percentage of UV (50%? I didn't quantify it precisely as I was way too high for me to consider them further). Even the Scubapro D-Mask was still letting through about 5% of UV rays, which I wasn't too pleased with. I tested both UV-A and UV-B (combined test: I didn't test UV-A and UV-B separately).

Scuba masks can be made from tempered glass, @FranckDernoncourt, I guess those are then not UV protective unless specifically coated. I'm not sure if there exist tempered glass swimming goggles (I did not see any when I was still swimming and buying those occasionally) as pertaining to this question.

yeah, scuba mask lenses are often made out of glass. It's been a few years since i was swimming regularly, but i can't remeber any of my swimming goggles being made of glass.

@AnoE It's not safe to assume no goggles have glass lenses. https://www.cressiusa.com/Catalogue/Details.asp?SchedaID=342
Also it's not really a myth, because it used to be true. Before the 80s, polycarbonate lenses were rare, and there are still a few of us ancient folks around who were alive back then.
The best advice to give someone is to be sure their lenses block both UVA and UVB.

@AnoE Huh, interesting - my optometrist has it on their webpage, they even have references, though when checked out, the references are talking about intraocular lenses (i.e. contact lenses) rather than sunglasses. Seems like most provide reduction through material use, though almost all talk about coating as well. No time for a deep dive now, but I might come back to it at some point.

Note that some sunscreens are very toxic to sea life in some regions, so that may be a consideration.

@AnoE airace3 Thanks, good point, you're right, the diving masks I UV tested were made from tempered glass. Why are swimming goggles typically made from a different material than diving masks?

regarding sunglasses, pupil opening, and UV blocking, it's very easy: glasses that block UVs are certified, and you can check the certification when buying them (in the EU, I assume other regions have similar regulations)

Material: Lycra (aka Spandex or elastane) seems preferable over Neoprene. From saintjacques-wetsuits.com:

The lycra top is generally less expensive than the Neoprene top because it protects from UV and from friction but it does not keep you warm as the neoprene top do.

Also, Lycra gear is more flexible than Neoprene gear, which makes Lycra more suitable to swimming.
Regarding components:

2-piece (long-sleeve shirt + pants) or 1-piece wetsuit, sometimes referred to as dive skin.
Swimming socks.
Diving hood (if not already included in the wetsuit) + scuba mask, or facekini + anti-UV goggles.

That's the summary of my findings so far, any comments or improvements are welcome.
One weakness is that there is a small gap of exposed skin between the diving hood, the scuba mask and the snorkel tube:

(Image source: OpenAI ChatGPT)
